# How can I save list of opened tabs in Intellij Idea, when I switch git branch?

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij Idea 2018.1, when I switch git branch, list of opened tabs is changed (for each branch, own list). How disable this option (in previous version there was another behavior)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Disable the **Restore workspace on branch switching** option in Settings | Version Control | Confirmation

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response but I realized this is only going to work if you switch branches using IntelliJ, if you switch branches with another tool that is not going to work.

Comment: Checking out from within PHPStorm Git menu didn't change the tabs, even though I have the option checked.